# How to map available duration with weekdays across different timezone in javascript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

Availability (days and duration) mentioned here

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday 3:30 AM to 9:30 PM IST(GMT +5:30)
```

This availability for someone in Iceland(GMT) will be

```
Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday 10:00 PM to 4 PM
```

The same availability for someone in Brisbane(GMT +10) will be

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday 8:00 AM to 2 AM
```

Given input as the days(mon, tue, wed...) and duration (eg. 9 am - 4 pm) a source timezone and a destination timezone, how to calculate the availability in the different timezone.

1. take the start time and convert it into destination timezone, see if there is a day offset, return a plus or minus.
2. take the end time and convert it into destination timezone, see if there is a day offset, return a plus or minus.
3. if the above case if you receive a plus or a minus, add or substract one to the date.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you hoping to avoid using UTC in any capacity?

Comment: no, avoiding utc doies not make sense.

Comment: Right - I just hadn't seen you mention it so I wasn't sure if you were trying to avoid it.  It seems easier to take the input and source timezone and convert to UTC, then convert to destination timezone as necessary (then you don't have to worry about date offsets since it'll handle it for you)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getDayName(dateStr, locale)
{
    var date = new Date(dateStr);
    var options = { weekday: 'long' };
    options.timeZone = 'UTC';
    options.timeZoneName = 'short';
 return date.toLocaleDateString(locale, options);        
}
function getday()
{
var dateStr = '05/23/2014';

var day = getDayName(dateStr, "en-US"); 
//var day = getDayName(dateStr, "nl-NL"); 
// Gives back 'Vrijdag' which is Dutch for Friday.
alert(day);
}
getday();
```